# Computing a joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

In statistical inference by Casella and Berger, as an example of the fact that uncorrelated random variables are not necessarily independent, the authors show that if $X\sim f(x-\theta)$ where $f$ is symmetric about $0$ and $Y=I(|X-\theta|<2)$ then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

For this they claim that $$E(XY)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xI(|x-\theta|<2)f(x-\theta)dx$$
I don't quite understand how they arrive at this expression. What is the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ in this case?

Comment: Do you mean $I(|x-\theta|) < 2$ in the integrand?

Comment: I am confused with $f$, is the marginal PDF of $X$, right? May be you meant $f_X(x) = f(x-\theta)$?

Comment: @Carlos: Yes I meant $X \sim f(x-\theta)$

Comment: You should change $I(\lvert X-\theta \rvert) < 2$ to $I(\lvert x-\theta \rvert) < 2$, as suggested by @simonzack . I tried to fix it but since is a small edit I was not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that $f_X(x) = f(x-\theta)$. By definition

$$Y=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 1 & \lvert X-\theta \rvert \leq 2\\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right .
$$

and

\begin{align*}
E[XY] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X,Y}(x,1)dx \tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

We also have that

$$f_{X,Y}(x,1) = f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 1)P(Y=1) \tag{2}$$

Let's first compute $F_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 1)$:

\begin{align*}
F_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 1) &= P(X \leq x \mid Y=1)\\
&= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{F_X(x) - F_X(-2+\theta)}{P(Y=1)} & \lvert x-\theta \rvert < 2\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right .
\\
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 1) &= \frac{dF_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 1)}{dx}\\
&= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{f_X(x)}{P(Y=1)} & \lvert x-\theta \rvert < 2\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right .
\\
\end{align*}

Therefore, putting all together, (2) becomes $f_{X,Y}(x,1) = f_X(x)I(\lvert x-\theta \rvert < 2)$. Replacing this in (1) give us the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ is a function of $X$, therefore the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is degenerate, and you see in the integrand you only need to integrate with respect to the pdf of $X$.

Comment: I think that you should revise or explain why are you saying that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a [degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) distribution. That is not so clear to me. May be you meant a mixed distribution, in that $X$ is in general a continuous random variable and $Y$ is a discrete one?

Comment: Sorry I have not make it clear before. Since $Y$ is a function of $X$, i.e. it can be completely determined by $X$, conditional on $X = x$, $Y$ is just a constant - degenerate distribution. Therefore technically there is only a univariate distribution, but not joint distribution, just like you will not find the joint distribution of $X$ and $X^2$, or a general $f(X)$. Here the product $XY$ is just consider as a whole a function of $X$.

Comment: And for OP question, you are just calculating $E[Xg(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xg(x)f_X(x)dx$. If you are intended to find the "joint distribution" of $(X, g(X))$ first then it is not helpful for you.

Comment: This comments could consolidate a great answer indeed ;)